# On a conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked to find a one-to-one analytic map $f$ of unit disc $\mathbb{D}\subset \mathbb{C}$ so that $\mathbb{D}$ is mapped to $\{(x,y):y<x^2\}$.

I thought the core procedure could be done by certain one-to-one holomorphic function, say $g(z)=z^2$ on $(-1,1)\times(0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{C}$(which is one-to-one), but this maps to some field of parabolic that does not contain an interval: $\{(x,y);x\leq 1-y^2/4\}\setminus [0,1]$. I found it difficult to overcome the wield displacement of $[0,1]$, or was I going ahead in a wrong way?

Thanks for the comment below it suffices to choose domain such as $H:=\{\Re z>1\}$ we can get the desired conformal map. But now I am concerned if the target set is the other side of the parabola, say, $\{(x,y):y>x^2\}$? It seems function $z \to z^2$ does not send simple domain to the other side of the parabola, so how should I modify my conformal mapping at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of producing a parabola as the boundary curve by using $s(z) = z^2$ is right. You chose a bad domain for $s$, however.

Consider the half plane $H = \{ z : \operatorname{Re} z > 1\}$. Its boundary $\{ 1 + it : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is mapped to the curve

$$c(t) = (1-t^2) + 2it$$

by $s$. That is almost what we want, except for a translation to get rid of the $1$, a scaling, and a rotation. So we obtain

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2-1}{4i}.$$

It remains to verify that $f$ maps $H$ onto the target domain (into is very easy, onto a little harder), and then compose $f$ with a Möbius transformation mapping the unit disk onto $H$.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It's quite a clear approach to consider $\{\Re z>1\}$! Alao what if the target domain is $\{(x,y):y>x^2\}$? (It seems choosing one-to-one branch of the function $z \to z^2$ gives the same side of the parabola)

Comment: $\{y > x^2\}$ is much harder. I don't see an easy way to achieve that at the moment. Still thinking.